# How to test helper functions which are invoked by google cloud functions in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, chai

I am using Firebase as the backend for my app. I am also using firebase-functions. My index.js looks like this (and more, but that's likely not relevant to my question below) -

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
admin.initializeApp();
const testRoutes  = require("./routes/testRoutes");
app.use(testRoutes)
```

The directory structure for my project looks like this

```
 
+public
+functions
----routes
----test
```

The function I want to test is in a file testRoutes.js which is in the folder "routes". This function is neither HTTP nor callable. Rather it is called by the post request handler in the express app, which serves some requests from the client app. E.g. I want to test myFunctionToTest() which is placed in testRoutes.js like this -

```
router.post("/testRoutes/", (request, response) => {
   //Some conditions being checked, on success call
   myFunctionToTest(paramString);
}
 
function myFunctionToTest(paramString){
   //modify the string
   return modifiedString;
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to unit test these functions on firebase. I tried this -

1. Installed Mocha/Chai
2. Created a directory "test" in my "functions" directory and created a file called "index.test.js" in the test directory.
3. Wrote the testing script based on firebase documentations. Here is how my index.test.js script looks like this:

```
    const assert = require("chai").assert;
    const test = require("firebase-functions-test")(
      {
        databaseURL: "xxx",
        storageBucket: "yyy",
        projectId: "myproject",
      },
      "path/to/project_key.json"
    );

   
     const assert = require("chai").assert;
        const test = require("firebase-functions-test")(
          {
            databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "myproject.appspot.com",
            projectId: "myproject",
          },
          "path/to/project_key.json"
        );
    

        const myFunctions = require("../index");
        const testFunctions = require("../routes/testRoutes");
    
        describe("Testing my functions", () => {
          it("Testing myFunctionToTest()", () => {
            assert.strictEqual(
              testFunctions.myFunctionToTest("completed"),
              "completed"
            );
          });
        });
```

But when I run the test script, it throws the error below -

```
TypeError: stcFunctions.myFunctionToTest is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.test.js:15:39)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Now, I have tried to sift through the firebase documentation around testing the cloud functions but can not seem to find the relevant discussion/instructions on how to test helper functions like the function "myFunctionToTest()" - which aren't HTTP or callable functions but are being invoked as shown above. What am I doing wrong here?